# My app does not support the required ABI - x86_64

Tags: android, x86-64, abi

I created an Android app and uploaded it to Google Play. It appeared that it doesn't work for most of the devices. What I see in Google Play Console is following message:

`Android app does not support the required ABI - x86_64`

The project is not using any NDK or something like this. It's standard project which should work on most of the devices. I have tested .apk separately on Galaxy S8 and it worked fine. But if I want to download it from Google Play it shows that device is not compatible.

I suspect, that this issue occurs because I am using non Android dependency in my project : 
[Link](https://github.com/marvin-we/steem-java-api-wrapper)

How can I solve this?

Comment: did you resolve this issue ??

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem because of taking off a library/dependency,
in my case that lib is

> implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.8'

so I put it back to my gradle and resolved the problem, but I still can't find the precisely answer why but maybe you can recheck all of your dependencies